# Is there a way to set the text format when sending content via the email alert node

Tags: flowgear

When sending the contents of a text file via the Email Alert it converts the text to UCS-2 Little Endian from UTF-8. Is there a way to force the text format so as to make sure the package is the same as the file generated?

I have tried generating the file in Binary and turning off HTML Body. Do I need to use a formatter maybe?

Comment: The Email Alert Node shouldn't be doing any encoding changes on string content. Is this a value you're trying to use on the Body property or as the content for an attachment? If the latter, ensure that when you obtain that content it's treated as binary at the source.

Comment: Hi Daniel, thanks for the response. I am passing the Content of a file node to the attachment field. The same attachment saved via dropzone comes out UTF8 but once sent via email and opened or saved it is UCS-2 Little Endian. I have changed the file create format to Binary.